# ¿como genero por medio de un método recursivo, el dibujo que sale a continuación?, la verdad que ando perdida en cuanto al codigo

Tags: java

[image: Dibujar un circulo de radio r en el punto x,y]

LA verdad es que ando perdida en lo que es recursividad, se lo básico y me es imposible crear un método para generar el dibujo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deberias usar esta funcion:

```
public void dibujarCirculosRecursivos(x, y, r, n) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        float desp = r/2;
        dibujarCirculo(x, y, r);
        dibujarCirculosRecursivos(x+desp, y, desp, n-1);
        dibujarCirculosRecursivos(x-desp, y, desp, n-1);
    }
}
```

Suponiendo que el origen de coordenadas es el (0,0) el radio del curculo grande 5 y quieres hacer 5 circulos:
dibujarCirculosRecursivos(0, 0, 5, 4);

La explicación esta en que como los circulos se van duplicando en cada nivel interior (El circulo grande engloba a dos la mitad de grandes y cada uno de estos a su vez a otros dos) hay que ejecutar la función 'dibujarCirculo' una vez y las funciones dibujarCirculosRecursivos dos veces, una para dibujar un circulo la mitad de grande que el actual desplazado hacia la derecha y otro desplazado hacia la izquierda.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! (: